# How do I use Scala dispatch to get the URL returned in a 301 redirect?

Tags: scala, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, scala-dispatch

I am using Scala [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) HTTP library, version 0.10.1. I make a request to a URL that returns an HTTP 301, permanent redirect. For example, http://wikipedia.com returns a 301 that redirects to http://www.wikipedia.org/. How do I do I use dispatch to get the redirected URL?

Following the tutorial, here's what I've done.

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._
val svc = url("http://wikipedia.com")
val r = Http(svc OK as.String)
r()
```

This throws a "Unexpected response status: 301" exception. Presumably I need to either query the `r` value for the redirected URL, or maybe specify some argument other than `OK` in its definition, but I can't figure out what to do from the documentation.

Comment: Dispatch has changed a lot from 0.8 to 0.9 to 0.10 so you should state which version you're using.

Comment: Updated the original question. I'm using the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Configure the underlying asyncClient to follow redirects:

```
val r = Http.configure(_ setFollowRedirects true)(svc OK as.String)
```

To get the redirected URL:

```
val svc = url("http://wikipedia.com/")
val r = Http(svc > (x => x))
val res = r()

println(res.getHeader("Location"))
```

Comment: That worked. Now how do I get the actual new URL http://www.wikipedia.org/ from `r`?

Comment: You can also write `def redir(s:String) = {val r = Http(url(s) > (x => x.getHeader("Location")));r()}`

Comment: If `setFollowRedirects` didn't work for you, try `setFollowRedirect` (without trailing `s`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

dispatch / reboot v1.2.0:

```
  val myRequest = url(theUrl)
  
  def myGet = myRequest.GET
  def myGetFollowRedi = myGet.setFollowRedirects(true)

  def myRequestWithHeader = myGetFollowRedi <:< Map(
    "User-Agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.",
    "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.",
    "Accept-Language" -> "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4,nl-NL;q=0.3,nl;q=0.1",
    "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
    "DNT" -> "1",
    "Connection" -> "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest" -> "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode" -> "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site" -> "none",
    "Sec-Fetch-User" -> "?1"
  )
```