# Http.configure(_ setFollowRedirects true)(svc OK as.String) giving OutOfMemory error saying too many open files

Tags: asynchttpclient

I have tried

```
val r = Http.configure(_ setFollowRedirects true)(svc OK as.String)
```

It worked though, but it started giving OutOfMemory error saying too many open files on system etc. Is there any way to set max redirect-limit and close the connection to prevent OOM error. Please suggest. Thanks..

Ref URL:[How do I use Scala dispatch to get the URL returned in a 301 redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112493/how-do-i-use-scala-dispatch-to-get-the-url-returned-in-a-301-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously with [setting maxRedirects](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/e418d627107e1e797ea4d03e6b93e2a356ee995e/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig.java#L733) in the config. But then, this is just a security. You'd better try to understand why you end up with a endless redirect loop and fix it.